# Upload file into Codemirror textarea

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Has anyone tried doing this? I have a textarea made with codemirror fill and submit to a server which does some analysis and returns some data. I want to have the option to upload a file (via button or drop) but while I'm sure there is a way to do so with a normal textarea I wonder if it works with codemirror.

(It's in html/js)

Thanks!

Comment: Please find my sample code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55791565/10220825

Answer (score 0):

You can use File API (FileReader) for reading file and setting his value to CodeMirror editor.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.readAsText(f);
reader.onload = function(){ cm.setValue(reader.result); }
```