# Downloading and Uploading in CodeMirror Textarea and Skulpt Execution Issues

Tags: javascript, download, upload, codemirror, skulpt

This question has moved to [Skulpt and CodeMirror Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598668/skulpt-and-codemirror-issues) because the answers I had did not answer the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skulpt and CodeMirror Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598668/skulpt-and-codemirror-issues)

Answer (score 6):

**Here is the code snippet**

```js
var delay;

// Initialize CodeMirror editor
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
  mode: {
    name: "python",
    version: 2,
    singleLineStringErrors: false
  },
  tabMode: 'indent',
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
  autoCloseTags: true
});

// Live preview
editor.on("change", function() {
  clearTimeout(delay);
  delay = setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);
});

function updatePreview() {
  var previewFrame = document.getElementById('preview');
  var preview = previewFrame.contentDocument || previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
  preview.open();
  preview.write(editor.getValue());
  preview.close();
}
setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);

function saveTextAsFile() {
  var textToWrite = editor.getValue();
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
  });
  var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("pile").value + ".py";

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  if (window.webkitURL != null) {
    // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
    // without actually adding it to the DOM.
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  } else {
    // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
    // before it can be clicked.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  }

  downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadfile(input) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    editor.setValue(e.target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
}

var input = document.getElementById("select");

function selectTheme() {
  var theme = input.options[input.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  editor.setOption("theme", theme);
}

var choice = document.location.search &&
  decodeURIComponent(document.location.search.slice(1));
if (choice) {
  input.value = choice;
  editor.setOption("theme", choice);
}

//COPIED AND EDITED ALL THE BELOW FROM SKULPT
// output functions are configurable.  This one just appends some text
// to a pre element.
function outf(text) {
  var mypre = document.getElementById("output");
  mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text;
}

function builtinRead(x) {
    if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
      throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
    return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
  }
  // Here's everything you need to run a python program in skulpt
  // grab the code from your textarea
  // get a reference to your pre element for output
  // configure the output function
  // call Sk.importMainWithBody()

function runit() {
  var prog = editor.getValue();
  var mypre = document.getElementById("output");
  mypre.innerHTML = '';
  Sk.pre = "output";
  Sk.configure({
    output: outf,
    read: builtinRead
  });
  (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = 'mycanvas';
  var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
    return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
  });
  myPromise.then(function(mod) {
      console.log('success');
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log(err.toString());
    });
}
```

```css
.CodeMirror {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
iframe {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/mode/python/python.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="skulpt-codemirror.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="load-save-py.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="insert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<input id="toup" type="file" onchange="loadfile(this)">
<button type="button" onclick="runit()">Run</button>
Enter File name to save as
<input id="pile" placeholder=" ....without .py extension">.py
<button type="button" onclick='saveTextAsFile()'>Save/Download</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<textarea id="code" name="code"></textarea>
<br>



<pre id="output"></pre> 
<!-- If you want turtle graphics include a canvas -->
<div id="mycanvas"></div>
```

Open the snippet in a new window and Run it.  It works well.

**Here is the full code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/mode/python/python.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="skulpt-codemirror.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="load-save-py.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="insert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Python Editor</title>
<style type='text/css'>
.CodeMirror {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;}

iframe {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>



    <input id="toup" type="file" onchange="loadfile(this)">
    <button type="button" onclick="runit()">Run</button> 
    Enter File name to save as<input id="pile" placeholder=" ....without .py extension">.py
    <button type="button"  onclick='saveTextAsFile()'>Save/Download</button><br><br><br>
    <textarea id="code" name="code"></textarea><br>



<pre id="output" ></pre> 
<!-- If you want turtle graphics include a canvas -->
<div id="mycanvas"></div> 


<script>
var delay;

// Initialize CodeMirror editor
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
    mode: {
                name: "python",
                version: 2,
                singleLineStringErrors: false
            },
    tabMode: 'indent',
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    autoCloseTags: true
});

// Live preview
editor.on("change", function() {
    clearTimeout(delay);
    delay = setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);
});

function updatePreview() {
    var previewFrame = document.getElementById('preview');
    var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
    preview.open();
    preview.write(editor.getValue());
    preview.close();
}
setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);

function saveTextAsFile() {
    var textToWrite = editor.getValue();
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("pile").value + ".py";

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null)
    {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);}

function loadfile(input){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        editor.setValue(e.target.result);};
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);}

    var input = document.getElementById("select");

    function selectTheme() {
      var theme = input.options[input.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
      editor.setOption("theme", theme);
    }

    var choice = document.location.search &&
               decodeURIComponent(document.location.search.slice(1));
    if (choice) {
      input.value = choice;
      editor.setOption("theme", choice);
    }

    //COPIED AND EDITED ALL THE BELOW FROM SKULPT
    // output functions are configurable.  This one just appends some text
// to a pre element.
function outf(text) { 
    var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 
    mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text; 
} 
function builtinRead(x) {
    if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
            throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
    return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
}
// Here's everything you need to run a python program in skulpt
// grab the code from your textarea
// get a reference to your pre element for output
// configure the output function
// call Sk.importMainWithBody()
function runit() { 
   var prog = editor.getValue(); 
   var mypre = document.getElementById("output"); 
   mypre.innerHTML = ''; 
   Sk.pre = "output";
   Sk.configure({output:outf, read:builtinRead}); 
   (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = 'mycanvas';
   var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
       return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
   });
   myPromise.then(function(mod) {
       console.log('success');
   },
       function(err) {
       console.log(err.toString());
   });
} 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the file loads, but it creates a new blank textarea underneath.

Comment: how would I delete the original one?

Comment: and also (like I asked in the description of the bounty) can you give me the full javascript and html I would use instead of my old code

Comment: @DanielHarrin.....just to be clear. If I can get a code that is working directly on the browser but not on jsFiddle, will I still be eligible for the bounty?

Comment: yes, as long as you paste the full code in your answer

Comment: @DanielHarrin.....I have edited my answer with my full code, let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: that works, but it makes a new textarea in doing so above the old one - can we delete the old one?

Comment: also, can the `copytoeditor()` function be called when the open button is clicked to save there having to be another button?

Comment: yep, I can't get rid of that duplicate textarea, can you?

Comment: yes, I think that is a problem. Having a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17646555/6395782) . It pulls up the Codemirror straight away, however, we still have to do a soft refresh to get the code on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121863/discussion-between-daniel-harrin-and-dannyboi).

Comment: @DanielHarrin..... The code is now working , a small tweak did the trick ,
`editor.setValue(e.target.result);` I found the solution here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17959261/6395782)

Comment: ok, so now can you change the code example so it includes my code please?

Comment: you have not used by code example to base your answer on - the html is not the same as mine, and the python.js is replaced with xml.js etc

Comment: I need an alteration - you made a mistake - you based the code in your answer on this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646555/filereader-and-codemirror-load-file-complication?noredirect=1&lq=1), not mine!

Comment: If you can fix this, you are in the running for getting the bounty

Comment: im actually stuck with the run() function,rest all is fine. pyhton mode dosent seem to be working, i tried a simple Hello World.

Comment: so how can we fix it? I see that someone else has answered, maybe their answer can help (they don't have source code with theirs)

Comment: by the way the skulpt does not have `run()`, it has `runit()`

Comment: I gave you the bounty but my question is still not answered - please can you get it working in Python please.

Comment: @DanielHarrin...thanks. With a little help from skulpt site and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39188587/6395782) i got it to work. I never knew such things were possible, Thanks.

Comment: it works, but it is not based on my original code / layout. Please keep html css the same, only change the javascript. Thanks

Comment: I have just given you 100 reputation, please can you edit your answer because I have edited my question.

Comment: What operating system are you using? And what is not working?

Comment: I am using windows 10 chrome. When I awarded you the 50 rep, it was a different question to this one. Please read my question again as it has changed alot since you answered the first time.

Comment: i have now given you 150 of my rep, so you can fix it

Comment: you'll have to give me sometime, I have no clue about $$$ J query

Comment: ok no problem, take your time , or maybe someone else can help?

Comment: This question has moved, please look at the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598668/skulpt-and-codemirror-issues

Answer (score 2):

Use `editor.getValue()` and `editor.setValue(textFromFileLoaded)` rather than getting/setting the value of the "textbox" element itself.

A CodeMirror instance is almost entirely separate from the textarea it is constructed from. As you've seen, it won't notice changes made in the textarea, and won't propagate changes made in the editor to it (except specifically during a form submission).

Comment: can you give a sample jsFiddle / or some full code that works based on my question

Comment: This question has moved, please look at the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598668/skulpt-and-codemirror-issues