# Insert Text at Caret on CodeMirror Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror, alt

I am working on a Python editor and would like to add a feature to insert text at the position of the caret on a CodeMirror textarea.

There is a series of pictures which can be clicked. When one is clicked, the `alt` attribute of that picture gets saved, and then when you click again inside the textarea it gets copied to your mouse position (a demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t0k7yp7n/1/)

Here is a script for the text insertion part:

```
selected = '';

$('.insert').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('alt'));
    selected = $(this).attr('alt');
});

$('#textbox').click(function() {
    insertAtCaret('textbox', selected)
        // Clear the selection so it isn't copied repeatedly
    selected = '';
});

function insertAtCaret(areaId, text) {
    var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
    var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
    var strPos = 0;
    var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ?
        "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false));
    if (br == "ie") {
        txtarea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        strPos = range.text.length;
    } else if (br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;

    var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, strPos);
    var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos, txtarea.value.length);
    txtarea.value = front + text + back;
    strPos = strPos + text.length;
    if (br == "ie") {
        txtarea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        range.moveStart('character', strPos);
        range.moveEnd('character', 0);
        range.select();
    } else if (br == "ff") {
        txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
        txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
        txtarea.focus();
    }
    txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

And here is the CodeMirror textarea part:

```js
var editor;

//<![CDATA[
window.onload = function() {
    editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('textbox'), {
      mode: {
        name: "python",
        version: 2,
        singleLineStringErrors: false
      },
      lineNumbers: true,
      indentUnit: 4
    });
  } //]]>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/mode/python/python.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="skulpt-codemirror.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="load-save-py.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="insert.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dp6/CodeMirror/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Python Editor</title>
</head>

<body>
  Filename:
  <input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs">
  <button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save</button>
  <br>
  <input type="file" id="fileToLoad">
  <button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Open</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="#!">
    <img class="insert" alt="#1">
    <img class="insert" alt="#2">
    <img class="insert" alt="#3">
  </a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <textarea id="textbox" name="textbox"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button onclick="runit()" type="button">Run</button>
  <pre id="dynamicframe"></pre>
  <div id="canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I put them together in one file, though, when I click the pictures their `alt`s do not copy over to the textarea. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using CodeMirror, your `<textarea />` will be visually replaced by an editor provided by CodeMirror and most of your code relative to your `<textarea />` won't be usable as is.

What's going on on the background is that your actual `<textarea />` will first be marked with a style `display: none;`. Not displayed, no event binded on the `<textarea />` will actually trigger. Then, CodeMirror will actually add his own code to the DOM to display a new editor at the position of your `<textarea />` which is now not displayed.

For example, the HTML code for a newly initialized CodeMirror editor with the string 'Hello World' written in it would looks like:

```
<div class="CodeMirror-lines">
    <div style="position: relative; outline: none;">
        <div class="CodeMirror-measure">
            <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; overflow-x: scroll;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="CodeMirror-measure"></div>
        <div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;"></div>
        <div class="CodeMirror-cursors">
            <div class="CodeMirror-cursor" style="left: 74px; top: 0px; height: 13px;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="CodeMirror-code">
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <div class="CodeMirror-gutter-wrapper" style="position: absolute; left: -29px;">
                    <div class="CodeMirror-linenumber CodeMirror-gutter-elt" style="left: 0px; width: 20px;">1</div>
                </div><pre><span style="padding-right: 0.1px;"><span class="cm-variable">Hello</span> <span class="cm-variable">World</span></span></pre></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your `<textarea />` is no longer being used.

CodeMirror provides natively a programming API which can be used to do what you want. Basically, the steps required are:

- Check when the editor is focused.
- When focused, check if a picture has previously been clicked and if a `selected` text is available (the `alt` of the image).
- If yes, insert the `selected` text (the `alt` of the image) at the current position.

The JavaScript code associated to these steps would looks like:

```
// Listen to the editor focus events.
editor.on('focus', function () {
  // Only insert if a value has been previously selected.
  if (selected.length > 0) {
    // Fetch the current CodeMirror document.
    var doc = editor.getDoc();

    // Insert the text at the cursor position.
    doc.replaceSelection(selected);

    // Clear the selection so it isn't copied repeatedly.
    selected = '';
  }
});
```

You can check a working example on [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzsmtL4u/1/).

Comment: thanks for this: I have another featured question about CodeMirror if you want to answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075483/load-and-save-codemirror-textarea

Comment: Is this answer ok? I'll take a look asap at the other one if that's the case.

Comment: yes, thanks. I would be really grateful if you did look into it as the other answerer is having a bit of trouble, and you know how to use CodeMirror well!

Comment: What do you think of the other question? Can you answer it?

Comment: Hello again, can you help on a question to do with skulpt and codemirror? It is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075483/downloading-and-uploading-in-codemirror-textarea-and-skulpt-execution-issues/39125425. Thanks

Comment: Hey again, can you answer it?

Answer (score 1):

In Short, this code will replace code mirror current selection (or current cursor position when there isn't any selection) with a text:

`codemirror.doc.replaceSelection('text to replace');`